# object notation in verilog

Tags: mips, verilog, quartus

I am newbie to verilog hdl.

For testing a single cycle mips cpu, I am trying to use the following notation to initialize a register from the testbench.

`CPU.IM.memory[i] = 32'b0`

Here, CPU is one module which has a declaration for IM (another module) and memory is declared as a reg in it.

However, the Quartus verilog compiler is complaining that it cannot find the object reference. Is the above supported? I have a similiar problem in loading instructions in memory, I dont want to be able to do it from the testbench, instead of hardcoding or changing it in IM.

*TestBench.v*

```
for(i = 0; i < 32; i = i + 1) begin 
    CPU.IM.IMReg[i] = 32'b0; 
end
```

*CPU.v*

```
IM IM( 
//inputs 
    .address (pc), 
    .clk (clk), 
    .out (Instruction) 
);
```

*IM.v*

```
module IM ( address, clk, out); 
input [31:0] address; 
input clk; 
output reg[31:0] out; 
reg[31:0] IMReg[31:0];
```

Error being thrown
Error (10207): Verilog HDL error at TestBench.v(31): can't resolve reference to object "IMReg"

Comment: Can you show exact error and some code?

Comment: There is an entry about this error at [Quartus help here](http://quartushelp.altera.com/14.0/mergedProjects/msgs/msgs/evrfx2_veri_hierarchical_name_not_supported.htm) and [this forum question](http://www.alteraforum.com/forum/showthread.php?t=30807), seems like tool specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you're trying to do without seeing more of your code, but what I'm guessing is that you're trying to assign an internal signal (ie a signal not present on the input or output port list) of a module a value from inside a different module. Unless that value is a constant `parameter`, you can't do this. Only `parameters`, `localparams`, and signals on the port list (`inputs`, `outputs`, and `inouts`) are externally visible.

Usually, memories are initialized off of either a .hex or .mif file, which can be altered to represent the desired initial state.

Comment: Thanks wilcroft and @sharvil111, I'm providing the code snippet, hopefully it will make it clearer

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure that behaviors isn't supported, or you would have signals with multiple drivers, which would invariably lead to shorts. As mentioned, most memory modules should support some sort of initialization file. If not, add an `initial` block in *IM.v* and initialize the value there (either by reading from a file or as constant values).